# Getting an error in Angular on an http call about CORS

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cors, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting an error about CORS when trying to make a simple http get request to an amazon database that my colleague set up at https://ssj387shemh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test?TableName=Golf (slightly changed name for privacy) and I'm getting this error in my console -

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ssj387shemh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test?TableName=Golf' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

My service call function is as follows -

```
  getTeeTimes() {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.append('TableName', 'Golf');
    let httpOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    httpOptions = httpOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpOptions = httpOptions.append('httpMethod', 'GET');
    httpOptions = httpOptions.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpOptions = httpOptions.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, Content- 
    Type, X-Auth-Token');
    return this.http.get(this.url, {params: queryParams, headers: httpOptions });
    }
```

As you can see I've tried adding these extra headers in attempt to solve this to no avail. My colleague said that they enabled CORS on the server side so at this point I don't know what to do. Any advice would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Remove the last three calls to `httpOptions.append`. You don't need to specify the `GET` method via a header. Besides, no header starting with `Access-Control-Allow-` has its place in a request.